# logging a facebook user ID to a local database from a facebook 'like'

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, facebook-like

I am creating a site that allow users to vote on webpages similar to digg.com.

Users login with 'facebook connect' and logged in users can submit, vote, comment, etc and these details appear in their profile ie. number of submits, votes, comments, etc.

I have also added in facebook 'likes' to the system.  I would however like to be able replace the internal voting platform with facebook 'likes'.

What I would like to be able to do is identify *when* any of the site users vote on a facebook 'like'.  Although a facebook 'like' can be made outside of my site I am only interested when a logged in user submits a 'like' so this can contribute towards their stats.

Is this possible, if so how?

Thanks
Azzam

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. you can use `FB.Event.subscribe` to subscribe to the `edge.create` event. This will fire each time a user clicks on a `like` button. Example:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
   console.log(response);
});
```

More info on this [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe).

Comment: Fantastic, will let the developer know.  Sorry I can not rep+ since I do not have the privilege, but when I do I will give you a rep up.

Comment: I'm glad it helped you. p.s. Under the score of the answer should be a tick. Mark that if the answer helped you. You will earn points in this way, too. Cheers!